# pdo not always executing query

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I am using PDO with MYSQL. Sometimes when the code does an insert statement. it doesn't go though. This code has been functioning and doing it's job in my company for the last 8 months and now certain insert statements fail.

```
public static function update($id,$table,$fields,$output=false,$pool = false){  

    $sql = "";

    if($pool){
        foreach($fields as $fields_single){
            $fields_id = 0;
            if(isset($fields_single["id"])) $fields_id=$fields_single["id"];
            $sql .= self::update_sql($fields_id,$table,$fields_single,$output)."; ";
        }

        return max($id,self::exec($sql));
    }else{
        $sql = self::update_sql($id,$table,$fields,$output);

        return max($id,self::exec($sql));
    }
}
```

I have done proper debugging and everything is being passed to the function correctly.

and here is the exec function

```
public static function exec($query,$output=false){
    self::initialise();
    self::$query_count++;
    try{
        if($output) echo $query."<br /><br />";
        self::$db_connection->exec($query);
        return self::$db_connection->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
}
```

There are no errors thrown by the PDOException and it processes 1000's of sql statements each day. Any ideas or guess about why it wouldn't process an insert statement given to it, would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Also When i do lastInsertid() i get the new ID but i never see it in the database.

Comment: Your 2 examples are identical.

Comment: excuse that i fixed it. first function calls second function

Comment: Are you sure pdo is sending exceptions, are you doing something like `self::$db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` somewhere?

Comment: update_sql returns an sql string. It works fine. I checked the log and there were insert statements that it was returning that weren't getting executed. I tried to execute them myself and they worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
try{
    if($output) echo $query."<br /><br />";
    self::$db_connection->exec($query);
    return self::$db_connection->lastInsertId();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

with

```
if($output) echo $query."<br /><br />";
$count = self::$db_connection->exec($query);
if (!$count) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
return self::$db_connection->lastInsertId();
```

[`PDO::exec()` returns false on failure](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) looking at the docs there is no `PDOException` thrown by `PDO::exec()` - if you look at the docs for `PDO::prepare()` it explicitly says

> PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException

this isnt present in `PDO::exec()`

As noted by @jeroen in the comments - you need to look at how your error handling within PDO is setup - [read this on how using exceptions works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` is default - this will not throw exceptions